# Ways for the government to herd a massive amount of criminals into one place

Tags: magic

During the course of my fantasy story, a new group of people comes to an empire seemingly in search of peace. But they also bring new things like muskets and cannons to an empire once dominated by swords and bows. Understandably, this changes the entire game for the empire's criminal underground. However, amongst these criminals are powerful magic wielders once thought to be a disgrace. But now, these new people need them as a sort of fuel for a weapon, however, because they were thrown out and shunned they now do not trust the government and what they say. So, with the government of the original empire in on it, they need to get about 200 criminals as fast as they can into one place, capture then and proceed to harvest them for the "fuel". I have gone through many different possible scenarios but nothing seems logical. 
Note that they have things such as airships, and now Napolianic age technology as well.

Comment: I believe you are either looking for something like a prison or a concentration camp. How many people are we talking about? How long do they have to survive if they get burned for fuel? If I understand it correctly, you also only want to keep some of them, those that are magic users? Those prisons can keep a lot of guys, I would guess more than you need at the end

Comment: How big a group of people? How many citizens are in the country they wander into?

Comment: I'd probably cut out the last sentence. That sounds a bit like brainstorming for ideas. Just repeat your title and make that into a question such as "What are ways for the government to herd a massive amount of criminals into one place?"

Comment: What is Nepolianic age? a typo for Napoleonic (in which case I don't get the link with airships) or something else?

Comment: Your whole premise is somewhat flawed. Gunpowder weapons made a revolution on a battlefield, but they did not make significant impact on crime and law enforcement until reliable handguns were developed. And for those, you need factories.

Comment: I think they're called elections. :-)

Answer (score 6):

#### Announce that you grant them amnesty and lure them to your palace with promises of riches and safe jobs

They were criminals, thought to be a disgrace. This reads basically like "Nobody likes them". If you announce that you will grant any magic-wielder amnesty so that their crimes will be forgiven and promise to give them a chance for a real job with great perspective at the court of your king you will bait quite a lot of them.

Just mention that they will probably only have few contacts with outsiders and you can be sure that not so many people will ask questions if they never come back later. Just send a few of them outside from time to time to talk to others in the presence of your guards and let them live a comfortable life.

To "harvest" future generations you shouldn't "harvest" all of your magic users at once. Keep a few so that there will be future generations to "harvest".

Be careful when luring them to your palace. Make it so that they have to pass an "entrance assignment". Do some magic and we will let you through, one by one. Don't mention that you will catch them once they are through the door.

Make magic something useful, but tell your population that they should bring people with magical talent to your court. It will grant those people an "easy job" and the normal people will get a bit of money as a reward for <s>hunting down</s> finding people with this special talent.

#### Alternatively: Start a witch hunt - promise riches to whoever brings you a living wizard

That's the easier solution. Start a witch hunt. Everyone who brings you a wizard alive where you can test that he is a wizard will get a little sum of money. People will start bringing you the mages and you can easily "harvest" them. No need for hidden games. This will also eliminate the threat of people finding out about your lies. If you need a justification just tell the normal people that wizards are the cause for an epidemic or some other big catastrophe of the past. A moral high ground and the promise of money will make everyone start hunting witches. You might even create a new job with this.

Comment: This might be a good idea for political enemies and so on, but criminals that have not been caught yet will have little interest in showing up at one place to effectively confess to their crimes in the hope that the crimes nobody could prove they committed so far are to be forgiven. Also to the average Joe living a good and law-abiding life hearing that criminals that did all sorts of nasty stuff, maybe to him, maybe to people he knew, is kind of a slap in the face. If you are looking for them to get de-disgraced, this would accomplish the opposite

Comment: Although I agree with this idea, one thing that I did not mention is that some of these criminals no longer trust the government and would not care if they were given an opportunity to redeem themselves

Comment: @Unhappymarshmellow I added a paragraph. Please state all constraints in your question. If you need to work out details of a question before posting on the main site you can try the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions).

Comment: This has actually been done successfully, on multiple occasions, in the modern world, it really works extremely well, the offering a prize to criminals bit has anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Bribe one of them, and use him/her to set up a huge false flag. In other words, do not try to attract them as government; instead, attract them into a pretense resistance movement, or into a huge criminal scheme (or both - a criminal net that is also a resistance movement). Once they are in in sufficient numbers, round them up.

Consider keeping your readers ignorant of the plot, too.

Answer (score 1):

**The old order changeth.**

From OP

> But now, these new people need them as a sort of fuel for a weapon, however, because they were thrown out and shunned they now do not trust the government and what they say.

I took away that these new people - the ones with muskets - have taken over the old government.  These new people are the ones who want magic fuel also.

The magic users distrust the *old government*.  So: **the newcomers need to make clear that things have changed**.  Co-opt the magic users.   Make examples of members of the old government who most represent the pogroms against magic users, to show that they and their policies are out.  Make high profile magic users into high profile members of the government - for real.  When the rank and file of magic users see that the wheel has turned they will come in from the cold to take their own positions.

Once they are in, you need to be delicate.  With a little art you might be able to maintain a steady supply of these folks for fuel.  You could keep your highly positioned magic users as a sort of [Judas goat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judas_goat); these might or might not know of the entire fuel scheme.  Certain magic users would indeed keep governmental positions.  Others would be needed for the ongoing and highly dangerous overseas military endeavor.  Most (but not all!) of these would be the ones used for fuel.  When these magic users do not return they are honored with a military funeral and their families receive a pension, as with any soldier.

If you need the fuel fast, then the first ships full of these magic users (and other military) will (according to official report) fall prey to a sneak attack / Uboat type thing.  All the magic users will be taken to the fuel shop.  The non-magic users among them are necessarily lost too.  This event will be used to show that the enemy holds the same anti-magic prejudices as the old government and might even be in league with refugees from the old government.  The event provides your fuel and at the same time strengthens the perception by magic users that the new government is on their side.  Maybe it really is on their side!  Just like humans are on the side of cows.